# From dataset year select corresponding column of that year

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| Area | Year | Success_Year1 | Success_Year2 | Success_Year3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 33 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 44 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 23 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 53 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 |

Now i want to get a seperate column with sucess only in the year of the year column.
Like this:

| Area | Year | Success |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 |
| 33 | 3 | 1 |
| 44 | 1 | 2 |
| 23 | 2 | 3 |
| 53 | 3 | 4 |

How do I do this? Something like join? Select if?

I sought for something like

```
data_match <- data[ , grep("col", colnames(data))]
```

but then you would not iterate over the rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a 2-column matrix for indexing:

```r
df[grep("Success", names(df))][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Year)]

# [1] 1 3 1 2 3 4
```

Its `dplyr` workflow:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Sucess = as.data.frame(pick(starts_with("Success")))[cbind(row_number(), Year)])

#   Area Year Success_Year1 Success_Year2 Success_Year3 Sucess
# 1    6    1             1             2             4      1
# 2    7    2             2             3             1      3
# 3   33    3             3             2             1      1
# 4   44    1             2             1             4      2
# 5   23    2             2             3             1      3
# 6   53    3             1             2             4      4
```

***Note:** `as.data.frame` that surrounds `pick(...)` is necessary because `pick(...)` returns a `tbl_df` object which is unable to support indexing with a matrix.*

---

An alternative using `case_match`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Success = case_match(Year,
                              1 ~ Success_Year1,
                              2 ~ Success_Year2,
                              3 ~ Success_Year3,
                              .default = NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sapply` to do a vectorized `grep`, and `cbind` to do indexing by rows:

```r
data$success <- data[cbind(1:nrow(data), sapply(data$Year, grep, colnames(data)))]
```

```r
cbind(data[1:2], 
      success = data[cbind(1:nrow(data), sapply(data$Year, grep, colnames(data)))])
#  Area Year success
#1    6    1       1
#2    7    2       3
#3   33    3       1
#4   44    1       2
#5   23    2       3
#6   53    3       4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pivoting (here using `tidyr`/`dplyr`):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Sucess_Year"),
               names_prefix = "Sucess_Year",
               values_to = "Sucess",
               names_to = "YearCol") |>
  filter(Year == YearCol) |>
  select(-YearCol)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
   Area  Year Sucess
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     6     1      1
2     7     2      3
3    33     3      1
4    44     1      2
5    23     2      3
6    53     3      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi thanks for the answers! They did not work as expected but I found my own solution:

```
Datatable %>%
  mutate(Success = ifelse(Year == 1, Success_Year1,
                          ifelse(Year == 2 Success_Year2,
                                 ifelse(Year == 3, Success_Year3,
                                        ifelse(Year == 4, Success_Year4, NA)))))
```

Comment: Since you are using `dplyr` you may want to look into using `case_when` instead of multiple nested `ifelse` statements

Comment: Please check the update in my answer. Does that work for you?